# Use JSON transformer in Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a problem that seems unaddressed in any of the examples I can find.

My application reads an ActiveMQ topic of JSON messages.  It will build a completely new outbound REST call based on this data.  Note that this is not a "transformation".  It is given "X" produce "Y" i.e. ServiceActivator.

My flows thus far are

```
public IntegrationFlow splitInputFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("inboundJmsChannel")
            .split()
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG)
            .route(Message.class, m -> m.getHeaders().get("x-bn-class").equals("Healthcheck.class") ? "healthcheckChannel" : "metricChannel")
            .get();
}

public IntegrationFlow healthcheckFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from("healthcheckChannel")
            .log(LoggingHandler.Level.DEBUG)
        .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Healthcheck.class))
        .handle("healthcheckActivator", "process")
        .get();
}
```

There are dozens of examples on how to use spring transformers.  I have even considered trying a MessageConverter.  But I don't see why it would help and it doesn't seem to be the normal approach.

The main problem here is that Integration calls healthcheckActivator.process(String payload).  The payload itself is the expected valid JSON string.

I am a little surprised it does not call healtcheckActivator.process(Message payload) but But that wouldn't help so it doesn't much matter.

The real question is why does it not call healtcheckActivator.process(Healthcheck healthcheck)?

Well actually I understand "why".  It is because DSL generates an internal channel to tie the steps together and as far as I understand anything on a channel is a spring.messaging.Message.

I can easily instantiate my Healthcheck object once I get inside the SA.  But that leaves the nagging question: What possible good is the entire transform step?  If it always "serializes" the object back into a Message -- what's the point.

Like I said I think I'm missing something fundamental here.

**EDIT**
My new (and probably last) idea is maybe I'm publishing it wrong.

To publish it I am using

```
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(topicName, healthcheck, messagePostProcessor -> {
            messagePostProcessor.setJMSType("TextMessage");
            messagePostProcessor.setStringProperty("x-bn-class", "Healthcheck.class");
            messagePostProcessor.setStringProperty("x-bn-service-name", restEndpoint.getServiceName());
            messagePostProcessor.setStringProperty("x-bn-service-endpoint-name", restEndpoint.getEndpointName());
            messagePostProcessor.setLongProperty("x-bn-heathcheck-timestamp", queryDate);
            messagePostProcessor.setStringProperty("x-bn-healthcheck-status", subsystemStatus.getStatus(subsystemStatus));
            messagePostProcessor.setIntProperty("httpStatus", httpStatus.value());
            return messagePostProcessor;
        });
```

What arrives in the SI process(String payload) method is:

```
LoggingHandler - GenericMessage [payload={"healthcheckType":"LOCAL","outcome":"PASS","dependencyType":"DB","endpoint":"NODE TABLE","description":"Read from DB","durationSecs":0.025}, headers={x-bn-service-name=TG10-CS2, x-bn-service-endpoint-name=TG Q10-CS2 Ready Check, jms_destination=topic://HEALTH_MONITOR, _type=com.healthcheck.response.Healthcheck, x-bn-heathcheck-timestamp=1558356538000, priority=4, jms_timestamp=1558356544244, x-bn-healthcheck-status=SEV0, jms_redelivered=false, x-bn-class=Healthcheck.class, httpStatus=200, jms_type=TextMessage, id=b29ffea7-7128-c543-9a14-8bab450f0ac6, jms_messageId=ID:39479-1558356520091-1:2:1:1:1, timestamp=1558356544409}]
```

I hadn't noticed the _type parameter in the jms_destination header before.  But before I started screwing around with this (because it didn't work) that is the correct class name for what the other team provided.

I have not implemented a JMS message converter.  But the supplied SimpleMessageConverter seems that it should do exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding is correct; works fine for me, so something else is going on...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56169938Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56169938Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(() -> "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}", e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
            .transform(Transformers.fromJson(Foo.class))
            .handle("myBean", "method")
            .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }

    public static class MyBean {

        public void method(Foo foo) {
            System.out.println(foo);
        }

    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String foo;

        String getFoo() {
            return this.foo;
        }

        void setFoo(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [foo=" + this.foo + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
Foo [foo=bar]
Foo [foo=bar]
Foo [foo=bar]
Foo [foo=bar]
Foo [foo=bar]
Foo [foo=bar]
```

Comment: Thanks for the example.  I spent a long fruitless time looking at the generated class another team gave me.  But even after I made major changes to it I didn't make any progress.  But I dislike it when people never acknowledge when I tried to answer their question.  So this is my official thanks!

Comment: I'll look at this more when I have some time.  But for now the above still fails and this works exactly as expected in the SA  
  Healthcheck healthcheck;
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
  healthcheck = mapper.readValue(payload, Healthcheck.class);  Very weird.

Comment: Thinking about Artem Bilan response some more maybe I am looking in the wrong place.  I added the publish info and a log line of what comes off the queue.  @Gary Russell does this make any more sense now?

Comment: No; it makes even less sense now - the `SimpleMessageConverter` knows nothing about JSON so you must not be using it if you are getting JSON. Why don't you just set a breakpoint in the `JsonToObjectTransformer`?

Comment: Wow.  That seemed like a super good idea!   I rooted around in the implementations and set breakpoints.  NONE of them were tripped.  So it appears SI is not calling the transform at all.  I wouldn't have thought it could even do that.  Even if the mapping fails, which I've proven it doesn't, I would expect it to always at least call it.  I can't shake the feeling there is something missing from the JMS headers that I don't know about.

Comment: I don't see how that's possible; are you sure you don't have another flow with the same bean name that doesn't have the `.transform()` step? Turn on DEBUG logging and watch the messages move between components.

Comment: This is just heartbreaking!  The ENTIRE problem was that I didn't put the @ Bean annotation on the healthcheck flow.  In the OP I cut & pasted and lopped off the first Bean.  But it legit is missing on the second.  Your idea to debug the transformer is what finally got it through my pea brain.  @Garry Russell you deserve sainthood for putting up with idiots!  Please excuse me now while I spend the afternoon beating my head on the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Spring Integration is a *Messaging* framework. It transfers messages from endpoint to endpoint via channels in between. That's already the target endpoint responsibility to deal with consumed message the proper way. The framework doesn't care about the `payload`. It is really a business part of the target application. That's how we can make framework components as generic as possible leaving the room for target business types for end-users.

Anyway the Framework provides some mechanisms to interact with payloads. We call it *POJO method invocation*. So, you provide some business with arbitrary contract, however following some Spring Integration rules: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/#service-activator.

So, according your description it is really a surprise that it doesn't work for `healtcheckActivator.process(Healthcheck healthcheck)`. Your `transform(Transformers.fromJson(Healthcheck.class))` should really produce a `Message` with `Healthcheck` object as a payload. The framework consults a method signature and tries to map a payload and/or headers to the method invocation arguments, having the whole message as a container for data to delegate to the method call.

From here it would be great to see your `healtcheckActivator.process()` method to determine why the `transform(Transformers.fromJson(Healthcheck.class))` result cannon be mapped to that method arguments.